# Is it possible to use a .tga texture file and a mix shader in the node editor?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

[image]

What I'm trying to do is render this ball from a video game as gold, with the .tga layer very faint on the top.  How would I go about doing this?

In the node control panel, when I click "use nodes", the .tga file seems to go away.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you click *Use Nodes* you have to, well, use nodes! That means also using a node for your TGA texture